# Evaluate the integral of $\frac{dx}{(x^2 +1)^{3/2}}$

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the integral
$$
\int{{\rm d}x \over \vphantom{\LARGE A}\left(\,x^{2} + 1\,\right)^{3/2}}\,.
$$

I'm stuck at changing $\left(\,x^{2} + 1\,\right)^{3/2}$ to an expression without radicals.

I subbed in $\sec\left(\,\theta\,\right)$ for $x$ and got
$\left[\sec^{2}\left(\,\theta\,\right) + 1\,\right]^{3/2}$.

I really don't know where to go from here. Maybe raise what's inside to $2/3$ ?, But I know I can't just do that.

Comment: Is it $\left(\,^{3}\,\right)/2$ or $^{3/2}$ ?.

Comment: A power of 3/2. Your second one there

Comment: Fine. Thanks.$\mbox{}$.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to evaluate without a CAS. But I think the answer is
$
\frac{3\,\mathrm{asinh}\left( x\right) }{8}+
\frac{x\,\sqrt{\left( {x}^{2}+1\right)^{3} } }{4}+
\frac{3\,x\,\sqrt{{x}^{2}+1}}{8} \
$

Answer (score 0):

The substitution you seek is $x=\tan t$, and the relevant formulas are $\tan't=\tan^2t+1=\dfrac1{\cos^2t}$